# Changing Links in Page Viewer

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-viewer-web-part

I currently have a page viewer on my SharePoint site. One of the links is outdated and needs to changed, is there a way to update/change the link without doing HTML?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean about "One of the links is outdated"? Where is the link? Is it a link display in the page viewer web part? Or it is the link of the page viewer web part?

If it is the link of the web part, you can edit the page viewer web part and directly change the link.
[image]

If it is the contents displaying in the web part, you can go to the source location to directly change the link.

(Page Viewer is the web part that displays another Web page on this Web page. The other Web page is presented in an IFrame.)

Comment: Hi, the link that is displayed in the page viewer is the web part itself. The webpage viewer is on the right side of my main page. It has content with 3 different bullet points and one of those bullet points links are outdated. How can I change the bullet point? Thanks! Sorry if I wasn't clear on the description.

Comment: Could you please provide some screenshots? What do you mean about "is the web part itself"? I think you need to go to the source page to edit the bullet point.